# How to insert a enum field with default value postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, enums

Here I need the default value for my enums if a null value comes.
by default, it is not working. I set the default value while I created the table.
if I pass default in values the default value will appear, but I have both null data and enum data for inputs.

```
INSERT INTO table(enum_value_1, enum_value_2)
VALUES (?, ?)
```

currently i am passing like this

```
INSERT INTO table(enum_value_1, enum_value_2)
VALUES (NULL, 'enum_value')
```

| enum_value_1 | enum_value_2 |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | enum_value |

but i need data like

| enum_value_1 | enum_value_2 |
| --- | --- |
| enum_value_default | enum_value |

Create table command

```
CREATE TYPE enum_candidate_status AS ENUM('attended', 'selected', 'rejected', 'not attended');   

CREATE TYPE enum_rating AS ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');  
 
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
candidate_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
first_name varchar(100), 
candidate_status enum_candidate_status DEFAULT 'not attended',
interview_rating enum_rating,
);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: `CREATE TYPE enum_candidate_status AS ENUM('attended', 'selected', 'rejected', 'not attended');  
CREATE TYPE enum_rating AS ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');  

CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (  
  candidate_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  
  first_name varchar(100),  
  candidate_status enum_candidate_status DEFAULT 'not attended',  
  interview_rating enum_rating,  
);`

Comment: The problem is that you're overwriting the `DEFAULT` value with a `NULL`. If the insert statement simply ignores the column, the default value will be stored. The best way would be to set the column to `NOT NULL`, or in case it is not possible you have to create an `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger to get rid of the nulls for you

Comment: Or instead of `NULL` you can use `DEFAULT` to get the default value to be used as in: `VALUES (DEFAULT, 'enum_value')`

Answer (score 3):

To manage this, you must use the function and trigger

Pay attention and do as follows. I do your example so that it is understandable to you.

at the first time CREATE TYPE and TABLE

```
CREATE TYPE enum_candidate_status AS ENUM('attended', 'selected', 'rejected', 'not attended');
CREATE TYPE enum_rating AS ENUM('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');  
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE ( candidate_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,  
                    first_name varchar(100),  
                    candidate_status enum_candidate_status DEFAULT 'not attended',    
                    interview_rating enum_rating);
```

then u must be CREATE FUNCTION like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION force_candidate_status_defaults()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
NEW.candidate_status := 'not attended';
RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

at the end u must CREATE trigger to control on ur queries as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_table_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON CANDIDATE
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.candidate_status IS NULL)  -- !
EXECUTE FUNCTION force_candidate_status_defaults();
```

now u can test query and enjoy it

```
INSERT INTO CANDIDATE(candidate_status, interview_rating) VALUES (NULL, '3') RETURNING *;
```